# Facebook javascript login sdk, feed undefined

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

i am using facebook javascript sdk to login user via facebook, 
here is the code.

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    console.log("this");
  FB.init({
    appId      : 'my app id',
    cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access 
                        // the session
    xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
    version    : 'version' 
  });

};

 (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.com/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

function testAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me?fields=id,name,email,feed', function(response) {
        var name= response.name;
        var email= response.email;
        var feed= response.feed;   });
```

it works fine, the problem is, it fetches `name` and `email` correctly, but does not fetch or print `feed` correctly, rather shows `undefined`, i tested on facebook graph explorer and there it showed the feed aswell i am new to use facebook sdk therefore i might be missing something.

Comment: In graph api explorer with this code you can get the feed 
`FB.api(
  '/me/feed',
  'GET',
  {},
  function(response) {
      // Insert your code here
  }
);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably forgot to authorize the user with the `user_posts` permission, the API call looks correct. Make sure you add `user_posts` to your scope parameter in the `FB.login` function. After that, it should work perfectly fine: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname%2Cemail%2Cfeed&version=v2.5

Btw, this is how you should use parameters:

```
FB.api('/me', {fields: 'id,name,email,feed'}, function(response) {...
```